# Samba shares from a Ubuntu 10.10 box are locked on a mac

Tags: macos, ubuntu, permissions, samba

I've got some shares on a mythbuntu machine that are set up thus:

```
[music]
      comment = music on mythtv box
      path = /media/music
      read only = No
      public = yes
      writeable = yes
      printable = yes
```

I can see them on my OSX laptop and if I look at the permissions it says I have read/write access, but when I try to write to the share I get an error saying that the file is locked or on a locked volume.

I have recently wiped the ubuntu OS partition and reinstalled, these shares are on a separate drive from my OS which weren't touched in the install. I had to manually edit fstab to mount them, so that could be another source of problems. However I have chown-ed them all to my ubuntu user account and on the mythtv machine they are all readable and writeable on the ubuntu machine.

As a side question, what is the difference between read only = no and writeable = yes, or indeed public in smb.conf?

Comment: one additional note is to try accessing samba the way you have it set up from several different OSes so you can isolate it to a samba problem or an OS problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAMBA is funny about things sometimes.  it's a lot of hackish patchwork, but getting better.  as far as using r/w vs public, r/w requires some form of authentication and public shouldn't.  i would google around a bit for working confs from tutorials and examine the differences instead of trying to use the right syntax based on logic.  it could have a lot to do with the order it interprets parameters.  i would try not using read only and writeable.  if they just flip an access bit without checking it could cause issues.  haven't tested or examined source so that isn't definitive, just a thought.  there's a discussion where jorge has samba working for a multimedia share over on askubuntu...he might have some pointers.  i answered a question or to relating to samba over there.  i'ld take a look at those discussions before i beat it up too hard.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by copying the files off the hard drive, reformatting it, and copying them back. I think it had something to do with the fstab and the way that drive was mounted.